# Remove Ith element

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

```
void removeIelement(Dlist& d, int i) {
    if (d.head == NULL) {
        cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        int count = 1;
        Node* cur = d.head;
        while (cur != NULL) {
            if (count == i) {
                Node* temp = cur->next;
                Node* temp2 = temp->next;
                cur->next = temp->next;
                temp2->prev = cur;
            }
            count++;           
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code to delete Node ith in doubly linked list

My doubly linked list is :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

But when I run this program  if I enter i = 1 it will delete

```
 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Same with i = 2 .... it will delete after element i (i+1)

```
1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Can you help me to fix this function? Thank you

Comment: your code simply deletes next element instead of deleting current element. Fix it. As a proof: there is no way for you to change `->head` variable, so you never remove first element.

Comment: It doesn't actually delete anything. It just leaks temp, which is the (i + 1)st node. Nor does it account for the case of deleting the head/front node, meaning that in the case of i = 1, the list would become invalidated if it successfully deleted the head/front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not deleting anything. You are linking around temp, but since it's never actually deleted, you just leak the memory instead. You match against cur, meaning you want to delete cur, but then you assign temp to cur->next. You are linking around cur + 1, which is why you always unlink (not delete) the (i + 1)st node. You don't need any temps, either; the list is doubly linked. Take advantage of that. Erasing is incredibly easy in doubly-linked lists. After the delete command, your function should immediately `return` as well. Its job is done.

This code does not account for deleting the tail node, since I don't know if you track that or not. If you do, you need to account for that scenario as well.

```cpp
void removeIelement(Dlist& d, int i) {
    if (d.head == NULL) {
        cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        int count = 1;
        Node* cur = d.head;
        while (cur != NULL) {
            if (count == i) {
                cur->next->prev = cur->prev;  // Added
                cur->prev->next = cur->next;  // Changed
                if (cur == head) {            // Added
                    head = cur->next;         // Added
                }                             // Added
                delete cur;                   // Added
                return;                       // Added
            }
            count++;           
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
}
```

This could have been resolved by just drawing it on a piece of paper. Doing that beforehand would have eliminated this issue altogether. Planning is one of the most important aspects of programming.

Answer (score -1):

A double linked list should have 2 attributes named begin and end, pointing to two "**empty**" places, head->next should point to the 1st element, and end->pre should point to the last element, your code assumes head as the first element, when it tries to remove the first element, it removes the element right after head, which is the element after the first element. A.K.A the second element.

the correct code may look like this:

```cpp
void removeElement(Dlist& d, int id){
    if(d.head->next==d.tail){
        // the list is empty
        cout << "empty list" <<endl;
    }
    else{
        int count = 1; Node* cur = d.head->next;
        while(cur->next != NULL)
            if(count == id){
                cur->prev->next=cur->next, cur->next->prev=cur->prev;
                delete cur;
                return; //removal successful
            }
            else
                count++, cur = cur->next;
        cout << "does not exist." << endl;
    }
}
```

note that I didn't test the code. There might be some issues, but you got the idea.

Comment: Begin, or head? Also, that's not correct at all. Head points to the first node, tail points the last node. If you have an empty node that points to the first/last, you'd only need one because you're designing a circularly linked list. Two empty nodes is needlessly over-complicated. Finally, you don't account for deleting the head node. I also subjectively disagree with your uses of the comma operator.

Comment: as you may guess, begin and head is the same. I've checked some of my peer's code and some of them do follow your comment, and some creates empty nodes. I consider this as a general coding style difference, Introduction to Algorithms also mentioned sentinels in linked list. As for the comma, I didn't like commas either. I used the stackoverflow code editor and typing brackets is quite painful, so that I decided to use commas. Thanks for the feedback though.